# Change text value with a before render variable?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to change the text value of a `TextBlock`, but the value is set before the render is initialized. What can I do? I built a static class to pass the variable but that doesn't seem to work (I need the variable to be initialized before render).

```
private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var name = "test";

    StaticName.Static = (name);
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TextBlock.Text = StaticName.Static;
}

public static class StaticName
{
    public static string Static { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like a code smell. Can't you set the desired value in the designer? Why does it need to be set in some way before rendering?

Comment: hi, i am using the api of steam, so dont work if its after render :(. what can i do to get the value of a variable from there??

Comment: Since this is tagged WPF, I assume you're using the Visual Studio form designer or Blend. You can set the contents of the TextBlock in the XML.

Comment: yes, but i have to pass it from a variable

Comment: Again, this seems like a "you're doing it wrong" type of approach. That said, open up InitializeComponent, copy the code that sets up the TextBlock from there and add it to your MainWindow constructor then delete it from the designer. Set the text from your variable. Profit?

Comment: I cant the variable "name" must be before any render

Comment: updated version with actual code

Comment: Do you know how to use WPF? I.e. do you know that 100% of your UI-displayed values should come from a view model, where the view model properties are bound to the relevant UI component in the XAML? If not, before reading the rest of this comment, go read about that and learn how binding in WPF works, and why your program needs to be based on that. Okay, now that you've done that: just set up your view model, then update the property in the `MainWindow_OnLoaded()` method. Data binding will then update the `TextBlock.Text` property value for you. The user will never notice it wasn't always set.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not working this way because the constructor always terminates *before*  the `Loaded` event occurred. So inside the constructor the value of the `static` variable `Static` is still NULL.

To fix it you must move the initialization of the `TextBox` into the `Loaded` event handler:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += MainWindow_OnLoaded;
}

private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SteamAPI.Init();
    var name = SteamFriends.GetPersonaName();

    personNameTextBox.Text = name;
}
```

This will make the `TextBox`to display the name as soon as it is rendered.

Comment: thank you, but now have an error  "
System.IO.FileLoadException: 'The file or assembly' Steamworks.NET, Version = 12.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null 'or one of its dependencies can not be loaded. An assembly with a secure name is needed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044) '"

Comment: @tester9 The error comes from the library or assembly  you are referencing. Steamworks.NET, is this 3rd party? Maybe you should try to reinstall it via Nuget. Do you use strong names for your assemblies?